# facebook login : Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-login, laravel-socialite

I did a project before 1 year in laravel and everything was fine since 1 year ago  but yesterday i got a notice about the problem.

I have tried to enter with facebook but the login didnt success .
I didnt change anything inside the page of the app and all the other login option work fine 100% (twitter and google ).

what is the problem could be ? 
why facebook didnt accepting my URL Now ??

here is the error

[image]

and this is all the setting as I think .

[image]

---

[image]

after the error I have set the privacy url because it was requirement and i have added the https ( I thought it will help to solve the problem . but it didnt )

Comment: Good thing you blanked all the relevant parts, otherwise someone could potentially spot what’s actually wrong ...

Comment: what ? ? ? I blanked only the domain name , and the id of the app , what is the information that you need ? ? I think there is no need to know the domain name to solve the problem . everything I blanked is same , even I didn't blank the https or http :)  it's just the example.org ?

Comment: and i told in the question , everything was fine since 1 year ago  , that mean 100% the information is correct because i didnt change anything since while . but I think the problem from the server not from the code or the app.

Comment: So what, all that means is that you did not bother to keep up with the changes Facebook announces ... https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after long time of search, there was other people who face the same error.
The problem is solved . 
it seems like there is a new update from facebook .

for me I didn't change anything inside my app .

the problem was because in my laravel ,I set the redirect link to be

```
'redirect' => 'https://****.org/auth/facebook/callback/'
```

but it seems like i have to remove `/` from the end of the link

the problem is solved with

```
'redirect' => 'https://****.org/auth/facebook/callback'
```

facebook was accepting the link with `/`  but not anymore today .